# Linking a Webpage to a Button in Android

Tags: android, eclipse

I am making an android project.. and I want to be able to click a button and it will bring me directly to a webpage.

Sorry for the little information, but I really have no idea how to do it.
For the button, this is the xml code I have..
I'm not sure If I have to code in the xml or the MainActivity file..

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/button2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
    android:text="@string/socs_button" 
    android:textColor="#0000CD"
    android:textSize="20sp"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following to your button xml

```
android:onClick="openSite"
```

In the controlling actvity Java

```
public void openSite(View v){
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("http://myurl");
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

```
Button button2 = (Button) dialog.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setData(Uri.parse("your site name"));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```